# 500 Internal Server Error on CodeIgniter 4 (Infinityfree hosting)

Tags: php, error-handling, hosting, codeigniter-4, http-status-code-500

When I press the submit button on a login form, suddenly my website displays an error 500.I am very new to website hosting. what's wrong with my website?

my htaccess :

```
php_value display_errors On
php_value mbstring.http_input auto
php_value date.timezone America/New_York
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is the function for route example.com/login/authentication :

```
public function autentikasi()
    {
        $petugas = new PetugasModel();

        $username = $this->request->getPost('username');
        $password = $this->request->getPost('password');

        try {
            $user = $petugas->where('username', $username)->first();
            if ($user && $password == $user['password']) {
                $session = session();
                $session->set('nama_petugas', $user['nama_petugas']);
                $session->set('username', $user['username']);
                $session->set('password', $user['password']);
                $session->set('telp', $user['telp']);
                $session->set('level', $user['level']);
                $session->set('id_petugas', $user['id_petugas']);
                $session->set('isLoggedIn', true);

                // dd($session);

                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            } else {
                // Display error message
                $session = session();
                $session->setFlashdata('error', 'Username atau pasword salah');
                return redirect()->to(site_url('login'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Display error message
            $session = session();
            $session->setFlashdata('error', $e->getMessage());
            return redirect()->to('/login');
        }
    }
```

my login form view:

```
 <div class=" px-md-5 text-muted">
                            <?php if (session()->getFlashdata('error')) : ?>
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?= session()->getFlashdata('error') ?></div>
                                <?php elseif (session()->getFlashdata('success')) : ?>
                                    <div class="alert alert-success"><?= session()->getFlashdata('success') ?></div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                                <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('login/autentikasi') ?>">
                                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="form3Example3" class="form-control rounded-pill" required />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="form3Example3" class="form-control rounded-pill" required />
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Submit button -->
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn text-light btn-cl w-50 mb-4 rounded-pill">
                                            Sign In
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Register buttons -->
                                </form>
                                <div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I'm confused. I've tried various ways but nothing works

Comment: sorry if my question is confusing, english is not my first language

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it.

Comment: I added 'php_value display_errors On' to the htaccess according to inifinityfree community's suggestion, but no logs appear, is there any other way to view the logs?

Comment: That would cause errors to appear on the screen, not in the logs

Comment: Another way you can enable on-screen reporting is: Enable error reporting: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors. https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ has a good guide to configuring logging

Comment: Also, occasionally a 500 error can also be caused by Apache, rather than PHP. In that situation the error would be in the Apache log, not the PHP log

Comment: P.S. Did you test your code in a local environment before deploying it to the host? Does it work there?

Comment: btw i found the problem, the problem appears because of routes error, don't know why if i want to display my website, i have to type example.com/public, if i type example.com my web doesn't appear, i have to go to 'public' folder so that it appears, when I press the login button on my web, because the login form action is '/login/authentication', the routes that go to 'example.com/login/authentication' without 'public' before '/login', I I want my website to be able to display directly only with example.com without /public, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That's weird.  A route error would normally be with error code `404` (Not Found) and not `500` (Server Error). 

Comment: yeah, very weird :')

Comment: Please,  share the specific `500` Server error you're receiving.  Otherwise,  any help you will receive will just be speculative.  Failure to do so, will make the question prone to closure.

Comment: @NewbieMF you have to point your server's document root to your app's `public` folder.